# Transparent scrollbar

Tags: css, webkit, scrollbar

How to make scrollbar transparent? **Only css**. Only for webkit browsers.
My [code](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/DpKyn) here.

```
   div{
  width:410px;
  height:100px;
  overflow-y:overlay;
  border:1px solid green;
  position:relative;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar{
  width:20px;
} 

::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb{
  background-color:rgba(0,0,0,1);
}
```

Comment: Consider using a `.png`

Answer (score 3):

```
div
{
  width:410px;
  height:100px;
  overflow-y:overlay;
  border:1px solid green;
  position:relative;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar{
  width:20px;
} 

::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb{
   background-color: rgba(255,255,255,1);

}
```

Comment: I need transparent scrollbar not invisible!=)

Comment: `rgba(255,255,255,255)` is not valid code. It should be `rgba(255,255,255,1)`.

Answer (score 0):

If you end up wanting it cross-browser, [see my question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19466750/scrolling-element-without-scrollbar-with-css) from last week.

[Here's the JSBin](http://jsbin.com/akEduMo/2/edit) to go with it.

Comment: Thanks. But it's not the thing I need