# Hiding scrollbar without affecting page width or shaky page re-rendering

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, browser-scrollbars

I have a div with position fixed (my dialog) which i give a higher z-index to takeover my page when a certain action is performed. Am trying to hide my scrollbar by doing `overflow:hidden;`without affecting the width of the page when the div takes over the page. Any suggestion how this would be performed??

```
html, body {
background: #FFFFFF;
font-family: "Avenir Medium";
height: 100%;
transition: overflow 0.37s easein-out
}

.div-dialog{
display: none;
opacity: 0;
position: fixed;
width: 0;
left: 0;
top: 0;
z-index: 0;
overflow: hidden;
background: white;
-webkit-transition: opacity 0.30s ease-in-out;
transition: opacity 0.30s easein-out;
}
```

[Jfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/o2ztuppp/) trying to replicate my result.The implementation am trying to realize is that of [myspace](https://myspace.com/) when you click the search icon at the top left

Comment: It might be helpful if you explained why you are trying to acomplish this as well as providing an example on [JFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/) or [Codepen](http://www.codepen.io).

Comment: Could you show a live example? Which scrollbar do you want to hide? The bar from your normal content or a bar which is cause by the overlay-div?

Comment: Check this [scrolling-element-without-scrollbar-with-css](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19466750) SO question/answers. Mayby that will work for you...

Comment: here's a  [jfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/o2ztuppp/), im my situation the browser width increases as i hide and shrinks as i display the scrollbar. there's also a fadein animation which makes it all the more visible

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Was finally able to fix my problem, by doing the following

```
    html,body{
     height: 100%;
     overflow: hidden;
    }
    body{
     overflow: auto;
    }
```

By doing this all my content stays within the body, so when an element has a position of fixed, it covers the scrollbar and its not affected by any change to its overflow,`overflow:hidden or overflow:auto`